# Angular Unit tests in Visual Studio failing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, jasmine, chutzpah

Having installed the necessary packages (Chutzpah, Jasmine and Karma), I made a simple Angular test to try testing (propped up in an MVC project), and I am having trouble with the tests.

When I run the tests in Karma from the command line, they pass. When I run them through ReSharper/Chutzpah in Visual Studio, they fail. My tests are running but I am having trouble understanding the errors.

MainCtrl.js:

```
var myModule = angular.module("MyApp", []);
  myModule.controller("MainCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.addNum = function(x, y) {
       return x + y;
    }

    $scope.fullName = function (x, y) {
        return x + " " + y;
    }

    $scope.age = 29;
}]);
```

MainCtrlSpec.js:

```
/// <reference path="../../AngularTesting/Scripts/_references.js" />

describe("Controller: MainCtrl", function () {
    beforeEach(module("MyApp"));
    var MainCtrl, scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller) {
        scope = {};
        MainCtrl = $controller("MainCtrl", {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));
        it("should have scope defined", function () {
        expect(scope).toBeDefined();
    });
    it("should add 2 numbers", function () {
        expect(scope.addNum(5, 4)).toBe(9);
    });
    it("should have a name", function() {
        expect(scope.fullName("Steve", "Jackson")).toBe("Steve Jackson");
    });
    it("should have an age of 29", function () {
        expect(scope.age).toBe(29);
    });
});
```

Karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jan 26 2016 13:05:20 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      'AngularTesting/Scripts/angular.js',
      'AngularTesting/Scripts/angular-mocks.js',
      'AngularTesting/ng-scripts/**.js',
      'AngularTesting.Tests/ng-tests/**.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: false,

    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

When I run the tests in karma, all 4 pass. In VS Test Explorer, it launches the Jasmine debugger but all 4 tests fail. I get the following errors:

```
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular (on line 1 of MainCtrl.js)
Error: Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery
Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.extend') 
Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.validator')
```

Also getting the warning:

```
Log Message: WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

Any help with these errors or warning would be welcomed, thank you.

Comment: might be worthwhile posting your karma.conf

Comment: @sdfacre added it, thanks for the help

Comment: just make sure you have got the same js dependencies added in references section in chutzpah.json?

Comment: @sdfacre I'm not finding the chutzpah.json file anywhere. any ideas where its typically located? I reinstalled chutzpah into the project to make sure I still have it.

Comment: maybe read about this first. https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chutzpah.json%20Settings%20File

Comment: did you ever figure this out @jacksonSD?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a chutzpah.json file. Chutzpah does not run off of a karma config file. Just create a chutzpah.json file next to your karma one and follow the documentation at http://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah

For example :

```
{
  "Framework": "jasmine", 
  "References": [
    { "Path": "angular.min.js" },
    { "Path": "angular-mocks.js" },
    { "Path": "src", "Includes":["*.js"] }
  ],
  "Tests": [{ "Includes":  ["*tests.js"] }]
}
```

Comment: if it doesn't use the karma.conf file then can I still use the ngHtml2JsPreprocessor plugin for Karma to test my directive?

Comment: Chutzpah != Karma. Plugins for karma and karma's config do not work with Chutzpah. If you would like support for something feel free to file an isuse in Chutzpah's github page or send a PR